# Swift prefersLargeTitles not working if there is a HeaderView in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5

I replaced a `TableViewController` to à simple `ViewController` (and a `TableView` inside of course).

I have a problem pretty strange:

- **If there is NO View** inside the TableView: ✅ it's working
- **If there is a View**: ❌ The title is not Large by default, I have to scroll to display it in large mode. (Which is interesting is that the View is not stuck to the top, as you can see with the screenshots)

When I arrive on the `ViewController`:

[image]

After a scroll:

[image]

This is my code:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
      }
    }
}

extension TestViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      0
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      return UITableViewCell()
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin. I have edited some of your questions, as I notice that you are using the quote block (`>`) as a general highlighter. This is not what it is for - it has a specific semantic meaning, which is that it demarcates a quote i.e. something said by someone or something (in a speech, manual, book, magazine, newspaper, blog, web forum, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by setting `preferLargeTitle` in storyboard instead of by coding.

Select the NavigationBar(not NavigationItem) of your NavigationController in storyboard.
In attributes inspector, make sure the 'Prefers Large Titles' is enabled.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set

```swift
navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

before pushing your `TestViewController`.

Works when I run in the playground:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

final class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        view = tableView
        title = "Large Title"
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension TestViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

// Present the view controller in the Live View window
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController())
navigationController.pushViewController(TestViewController(), animated: true)
// before pushing viewController set prefersLargeTitles to true!
navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = navigationController
```

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-enable-large-titles-in-your-navigation-bar

Comment: Nothing change with that method.

Comment: @KevinB, look my edit. You can run it in Xcode Single view playground.
Still not helpful? Did I miss something? Please be more precise. Cheers!

Comment: I got the problem when I add a view (as a header) in the tableView

Comment: How do you add the header to tableView? 
viewForHeaderInSection?